# function to spawn shell code in x86

Tags: security, assembly, x86, spawn, shellcode

I feel like this is such a basic question but i can't seem to understand assembly. I have a function that i've written in x86 to spawn a shell but it seems to be doing nothing. Can someone point me to the right direction?

```
    .global main
    .text
create_shell:
    push %ebp
    movl %esp,%ebp
    subl $16,%esp
    xorl %edi,%edi
    xorl %ebx,%ebx
    xorl %esi,%esi
    pushl %edi
    movl $0x2f62686e,%edi ;this and the next instruction movl is /bin/sh in hex
    push %ebx
    movl $0x2f7368,%ebx
    add %ebx,%edi
    int 0x80
    mov $1,%eax
    mov $0,%ebx
    int 0x80
    leave
    ret
main:
    call create_shell
    ret
```

Comment: You should step through with a debugger (gdb) to see what is  happening. You can also run your program through `strace` and it will show you all the system calls and parameters.

Comment: I can tell you that `int 0x80` will be wrong.You want `int $0x80`

Comment: And comments in GNU assembler use `#` instead of `;`

Comment: Don't see where you set EAX before the first `int $0x80`

Comment: thank you I will try that out!

Comment: am i close to getting the correct solution?

Comment: You aren't `push`ing your string data onto the stack.  You `mov` into `%edi` but then `push %ebx`.  Also, `add %ebx,%edi` makes *no* sense.  EBX is still zero so it's a no-op, and you don't want to add ASCII string data as binary integers anyway.  Use a `gdb` (or a GUI frontend like https://github.com/cs01/gdbgui/) and `strace`